# vim says "No mouse support", but only when I run git commit

Tags: git, vim

I like using the mouse with vim, so I have mouse support enabled in my `.vimrc`. This works just fine most everywhere, but whenever I run `git commit` on a specific server (Appa), I get an error message:

```
[tswett@appa git]$ git commit
Error detected while processing /home/tswett/.vimrc:
line    1:
E538: No mouse support: mouse=a
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Aborting commit due to empty commit message.
[tswett@appa git]$
```

I end up with a vim session that has no mouse support and no syntax highlighting.

If I run `git commit` on a different server, or on my local machine, I do have mouse support and syntax highlighting. Likewise, whenever I use vim to edit anything *else* on Appa, I have mouse support and syntax highlighting. If I remove the `set mouse=a` line from `.vimrc` and *then* run `git commit` on Appa, I no longer get an error message, but I also don't get syntax highlighting, either.

How can I get vim, `git commit`, and Appa to all play nice with each other?

Appa's operating system is RHEL 6.3 (Santiago); Appa's vim is version 7.2; and Appa's git is version 1.7.1. Here's my `.vimrc` (identical across all machines): https://github.com/tswett/setup/blob/c84c8908a04a1d925d90da3da4f2fc83bf56172b/.vimrc

Comment: Check `:echo has("mouse")` on that machine. If it returns 0 (with that message it should) then you will have to get another vim (e.g. compile it by yourself or find fuller version in the repository).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Does `vim` on Appa otherwise behave correctly?  That is, do you have the problem *whenever* you run `vim`, or *only* when using `git commit`?

If the former:

Are you sure that `git commit` is running `vim`?  Many applications default to using `vi` in the absence of any other configuration, and it's typical for `vi` to either (a) a very minimal version of `vim` missing lots of fancy features or (b) something completely different.

Try explicitly setting `core.editor` to `vim` and see what happens:

```
git config --global core.editor vim
```

Alternatively, you can also set your `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` environment variables.

Comment: This problem only happens when I'm using `git commit`. It turns out that, according to `:version`, `git commit` was using a "Small version without GUI" (and without mouse support), rather than the "Huge version without GUI" (and with mouse support). Running your `git config` command fixed it. The funny thing is, `vi` is a symbolic link to `vim`—how did git end up using the small version?

Comment: Actually, I'm wrong. On Appa, `vi` is an *alias* for `vim`. As far as I can tell, git was, in fact, running `/bin/vi` instead of `/usr/bin/vim`, which was the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Mouse support can be enabled or disabled in specific vim builds. You can look at which features are enabled/disabled using: `:version`. On the Appa machine you'll probably see `-mouse` in the list.

The only solution is to use a vim that's been built with mouse support,. Unless you control the server this means:

- compiling it yourself or obtaining a compiled executable for the platform,
- keeping it in a user-local `bin` directory, and
- setting the `EDITOR` environment variable to point to your own vim.